# linear systems?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading a book about linear systems, namely "Principles of LINEAR SYSTEMS and SIGNALS" by Lathi. The author states that the system to be linear must satisfies the superposition property which is 
$$
k_{1}x_{1} \rightarrow k_{1}y_{1}, \qquad k_{2}x_{2} \rightarrow k_{2}y_{2} \\
k_{1}x_{1} + k_{2}x_{2} \rightarrow k_{1}y_{1} + k_{2}y_{2}
$$

He gave this example, "Show that the system described by the equation "
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} + 3y(t) = x(t)  \qquad (1)
$$
is linear?

The solution is 
$$
\frac{dy_{1}}{dt} + 3y_{1}(t) = x_{1}(t) \\
\frac{dy_{2}}{dt} + 3y_{2}(t) = x_{2}(t)
$$
Multiple the first equation by $k_{1}$, the second with $k_{2}$, and adding them yields
$$
\frac{d}{dt}[k_{1}y_{1}(t)+k_{2}y_{2}] + 3[k_{1}y_{1}(t)+k_{2}y_{2}] = k_{1}x_{1}(t) + k_{2}x_{2}(t)
$$

from Eq. (1), if we substitute $x(t)$ with 
$$
x(t) = k_{1}x_{1}(t) + k_{2}x_{2}(t)    \qquad (This \ is \ clear \ to \ me)
$$

And he stated
$$
y(t) = k_{1}y_{1}(t) + k_{2}y_{2}(t)   \qquad  (WHY? \ \& \ HOW?)
$$
how did he get $y(t)$?

Answer (score 0):

An idea is that for a given input $x(t)$, we get an output (a solution) $y(t)$ which depends on what $x(t)$ is.
To show the system is linear, we must show that if the solution corresponding to the input $x_1(t)$ is $y_1(t)$, and if the solution corresponding to the input $x_2(t)$ is $y_2(t)$, then for any pair of constants $k_1, k_2$ it must hold that the solution corresponding to the input $k_1 x_1(t) + k_2 x_2(t)$ is

$$ k_1 y_1(t) + k_2 y_2(t) .$$

In response to your question about how he got $y(t)$: He didn't really *get* that $y(t) = k_1 y_1(t) + k_2 y_2(t)$. Instead he is saying : If we *let* $$y(t) = k_1 y_1(t) + k_2 y_2(t),$$ and we *let* $$x(t) = k_1 x_1(t) + k_2 x_2(t),$$ (where we are assuming that $y_1(t)$ corresponds to the input $x_1(t)$, and that $y_2(t)$ corresponds to the input $x_2(t)$, and that $k_1,k_2$ are constants)

then we see that the equation (1) is satisfied.

In other words, the system has been proven to be linear by the time we finish writing out the equation under the line

"Multiple the first equation by k1, the second with k2, and adding them yields".

The rest (i.e. the substutions) are done just to help us see that the (rather long) equation involving the $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2,k_1,k_2$ is actually of the same form as Equation (1), so as to convince us that $ k_1 y_1(t) + k_2 y_2(t) $ really is the solution corresponding to the input $k_1 x_1(t) + k_2 x_2(t)$.

Comment: I'm not convinced. I can see that $$x(t) = k_{1}x_{1}+k_{2}x_{2}(t)$$ because it is the input of the system, and based on that, $$\frac{dy}{dt} + 3y = k_{1}x_{1}+k_{2}x_{2}(t)$$ now where should I start to prove the superposition property?

Comment: Since $x_1(t) = \frac{dy_1}{dt} + 3y_1(t)$, it follows that 
$$k_1 x_1(t) = k_1 \left(\frac{dy_1}{dt} + 3y_1(t)\right) 
= \frac{d(k_1 y_1)}{dt} + 3 (k_1 y_1(t)).$$

Similarly, 

$$k_2 x_2(t) = \frac{d(k_2 y_2)}{dt} + 3 (k_2 y_2(t)).$$

Adding both together gives us 

$$k_1 x_1(t) + k_2 x_2(t) = \frac{d(k_1 y_1)}{dt} + 3 (k_1 y_1(t)) + \frac{d(k_2 y_2)}{dt} + 3 (k_2 y_2(t)),$$

which reduces to 
$$k_1 x_1(t) + k_2 x_2(t) = \frac{d(k_1 y_1 + k_2 y_2)}{dt} + 3 (k_1 y_1(t) + k_2 y_2(t)).$$

Comment: this is what I thought at the beginning however, if we use this method for the following problem $$y(t) \frac{dy}{dt} + 3y(t) = x(t)$$ we get that the system is linear however the system is not linear. This is why I'm not convinced by the the way he approaches the problem

Comment: I'm confused as to whether the original system is 2 dimensional, or are we dealing with a single equation? I.E. is $y(t)$ mapping $t$ to a number or a pair of numbers?

Regardless, to show a system is linear we need to take two known solutions of the equation $y_1$ and $y_2$, and show that any linear combination $k_1y_1+k_2y_2$ is again a solution to the equation.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following will shed some light.

The system is

$$
\dot{y} = -3y + x,
$$
which is a linear system with the solution

$$
y = e^{-3t}y(0) + \int_{0}^{\tau}e^{-3\tau}x d\tau.
$$

Now, the output $y_{1}$ due to the input sequence $x_{1}$ and initial conditions $y_{1}(0)$ is

$$
y_{1} = e^{-3t}y_{1}(0) + \int_{0}^{\tau}e^{-3\tau}x_{1} d\tau,
$$
and the output $y_{2}$ due to the input sequence $x_{2}$ and initial conditions $y_{2}(0)$ is

$$
y_{2} = e^{-3t}y_{2}(0) + \int_{0}^{\tau}e^{-3\tau}x_{2} d\tau.
$$

But what is the output due to initial conditions $y_{1}(0)+y_{2}(0)$ and input $x_{1}+x_{2}$?

$$
y = e^{-3t}(y_{1}(0)+y_{2}(0)) + \int_{0}^{\tau}e^{-3 \tau}(x_{1}+x_{2})d\tau,
$$
which is equal to $y_{1}+y_{2}$. This is the superposition part, and the scaling can be shown in the same way.